# GCC equivalent of /GS, /GL, /Gy, /Oi, /MD in MSVC

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc

I port a program developed in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2017 (in windows environment) to GCC (in linux environment). I am not quite familiar GCC compiler.

Does GCC has the equivalent compiler options of /GS (Buffers security check), /GL (Enables whole program optimization), and /Gy (Enables function-level linking), /Oi (Generates intrinsic functions), /MD (Creates a multithreaded DLL using MSVCRT.lib)? Thanks.

Comment: [The GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html) might be helpful.

Comment: For "whole program optimization" with GCC, look up LTO ("Link Time Optimization").

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. thanks for providing the material.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, this is really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here we go:

- [`/GS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gs-buffer-security-check) is roughly equivalent to [`-fstack-protector-strong`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fstack-protector-strong) [`-fstack-clash-protection`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fstack-clash-protection) `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`.  It also requires optimization (e.g., `-O2` or `-O3`), which is disabled by default in GCC.  `-fstack-clash-protection` requires target support to work properly, which may still be lacking on Arm.  For such targets, it's best to avoid using it.
- [`/GL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization) is more or less equivalent to [`-flto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-flto), although the required tuning is vastly different.  When using link-time optimization (LTO), you should repeat all compiler flags in the linker invocation.
- [`/Gy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gy-enable-function-level-linking) is comparable to [`-ffunction-sections`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-ffunction-sections) [`-Wl,--gc-sections`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.32/ld/Options.html#index-garbage-collection).
- [`/Oi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/oi-generate-intrinsic-functions) is implied by `-O2` and most optimization options.
- [`/MD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library) is meaningless on contemporary GNU/Linux; there are no compiler optimizations which assume that the process is not multi-threaded.  Multi-threaded applications need to be linked with `-lpthread`.

It may make sense to check your Linux distribution for additional build flags and mirror them (e.g., [`-Wl,-z,now`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.32/ld/Options.html#index-_002dz-keyword) for additional security hardening).

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I am looking for.